# Elegantly evaluating a function of two variables for two value vectors in R?

Tags: r, heatmap

I have a function of two variables and an interval for each of the variables. in the end I want to come up with a heatmap where a Point (x,y) represents the value of the function at that point, so I want to evaluate the function for every combination of two values within the respective interval.
The function takes two double values.
I found the outer() function, but I am not entirely sure that it is doing what I want. Is there any quick solution for this?

Thanks!

Comment: Please share a minimal reproducible example, i.e. data and code attempt.

Answer (score 0):

`outer` is really a good idea, provided the (x,y)-points form a rectangular grid. At least it is faster than `mapply` for example.

```
f <- function(x,y){sprintf("heat(%3.1f,%3.1f)",x,y)}

X <- 0.5*(0:12)
Y <- 0.3*(0:3)

X.matrix <- matrix(X,length(X),length(Y))
Y.matrix <- matrix(Y,length(X),length(Y),byrow=TRUE)

system.time( for ( i in 1:100000 ){ heat.1 <- outer(X,Y,"f") } )
system.time( for ( i in 1:100000 ){ heat.2 <- matrix(mapply("f",X.matrix,Y.matrix),length(X))} )
```

.

```
> system.time( for ( i in 1:100000 ){ heat.1 <- outer(X,Y,"f") } )
   user  system elapsed 
  22.71    0.00   22.83 

> system.time( for ( i in 1:100000 ){ heat.2 <- matrix(mapply("f",X.matrix,Y.matrix),length(X))} )
   user  system elapsed 
  57.03    0.02   57.53
```

.

```
> identical(heat.1,heat.2)
[1] TRUE
> heat.1
      [,1]            [,2]            [,3]            [,4]           
 [1,] "heat(0.0,0.0)" "heat(0.0,0.3)" "heat(0.0,0.6)" "heat(0.0,0.9)"
 [2,] "heat(0.5,0.0)" "heat(0.5,0.3)" "heat(0.5,0.6)" "heat(0.5,0.9)"
 [3,] "heat(1.0,0.0)" "heat(1.0,0.3)" "heat(1.0,0.6)" "heat(1.0,0.9)"
 [4,] "heat(1.5,0.0)" "heat(1.5,0.3)" "heat(1.5,0.6)" "heat(1.5,0.9)"
 [5,] "heat(2.0,0.0)" "heat(2.0,0.3)" "heat(2.0,0.6)" "heat(2.0,0.9)"
 [6,] "heat(2.5,0.0)" "heat(2.5,0.3)" "heat(2.5,0.6)" "heat(2.5,0.9)"
 [7,] "heat(3.0,0.0)" "heat(3.0,0.3)" "heat(3.0,0.6)" "heat(3.0,0.9)"
 [8,] "heat(3.5,0.0)" "heat(3.5,0.3)" "heat(3.5,0.6)" "heat(3.5,0.9)"
 [9,] "heat(4.0,0.0)" "heat(4.0,0.3)" "heat(4.0,0.6)" "heat(4.0,0.9)"
[10,] "heat(4.5,0.0)" "heat(4.5,0.3)" "heat(4.5,0.6)" "heat(4.5,0.9)"
[11,] "heat(5.0,0.0)" "heat(5.0,0.3)" "heat(5.0,0.6)" "heat(5.0,0.9)"
[12,] "heat(5.5,0.0)" "heat(5.5,0.3)" "heat(5.5,0.6)" "heat(5.5,0.9)"
[13,] "heat(6.0,0.0)" "heat(6.0,0.3)" "heat(6.0,0.6)" "heat(6.0,0.9)"
>
```